# Ruby convert array to hash using array index as keys

Tags: ruby

How can I transform the array `["a","b","c","d"]` into a hash where the key equals the array index + 1.  `{1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my work :

```
(1..a.size).zip(a)
# => [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"]]
(1..a.size).zip(a).to_h
# => {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"d"}
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I was going to suggest `["a","b","c","d"].each.with_index(1).to_a.map(&:reverse).to_h` or something, but this is much cleaner.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Another was `a.each_index.with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i+1] = a[i] }`... :D

Answer (score 3):

```
["a","b","c","d"]
.each.with_index(1).with_object({}){|(e, i), h| h[i] = e}
# => {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"d"}
```